# How to get amount of all entries of a certain type from IgniteCache?

Tags: java, spring-boot, ignite

I have IgniteCache<T1, T2> cache where data of different types is placed including the auth tokens of logged-in users (IgniteCache<UUID, List<'SomeObject'>>).
I want to get statistic about how many authorized users I have, so I want to get from my cache all this tokens and count them. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can issue a [Scan Query](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cache-queries#scan-queries) where the callback will only count entries containing token.

To speed it up, you can issue an [Affinity Run](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/affinity-collocation#ignitecompute-vs-entryprocessor) for every cache partition to make sure no data is sent via network.

Comment: I did as the link said:````
 IgniteCache<UUID, LinkedList<SomeObject>> cache = refreshTokenCache.getIgniteCache();
  List<UUID> list = cache.query(new ScanQuery<UUID, LinkedList<SomeObject>>(
    (k, v) -> v != null), Cache.Entry::getKey
  ).getAll();````
  
  And got exception: 
  class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Query execution failed: GridCacheQueryBean [qry=GridCacheQueryAdapter [type=SCAN, clsName=null, clause=null, filter=com.myapp.cache.impl.DurableCacheIgnite$$Lambda$743/1117951308@4ba1e4e5...What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you paste whole stack trace to the question?